# Extract gps data storage

Tags: c#, .net, gps

I am using dotSpatial labrary in c#, I only can read realtime data.
but my problem is this.. how could I extract gps data storaged in my usb-gps device (it is passive gps)?

device information

brand : landairsea
Model: Gps Tracking Key

webPage: http://www.landairsea.com/gps-tracker/gps-tracking-key

Comment: There are many protocols.  You would need to specify which GPS you are using.

Comment: device information

brand : landairsea Model: Gps Tracking Key

webPage: http://www.landairsea.com/gps-tracker/gps-tracking-key

Answer (score 0):

From looking at their user guide:

http://www.landairsea.com/downloads/past-track-10.pdf

You could use the past-track software to save the stored data as .las format.

I believe that DotSpatial has a LIDAR plug-in that can read .las files:

Dotspatial.Plugins.LiDAR

If you are asking how to write a C# replacement for the Past-Track program that connects directly to the USB however, I don't know exactly.

DotSpatial has a positioning library that is DotSpatial.Positioning that was originally ported from http://geoframework.codeplex.com/.  It is possible that this utility will have the capability to connect to your device, but I think it would probably only support a limited subset of GPS devices, and I never used it myself at all.

Hopefully that information is a little helpful though and will point you in the right direction.

Edit:

I have downloaded the Past-Track 10 software that is designed to retrieve data from the unit.  This in turn installed Antaris4 and u-blox5 USB drivers.  I think this is half of what you will need to write a C# app that can talk to your GPS and do things in code.  You can find the drivers on the web.  I think I found it here:

http://www.driverguide.com/driver/detail.php?driverid=1869444

But make sure you find a version of the driver that matches your PC configuration (32/64 and correct operating system).  Incidentally, that will probably mean you will need to make x86 and x64 builds for your C# app.

The next step is to find some documentation for it and then attempt to use the drivers from C#.  So far I haven't found a good document showing how to work with the drivers, but I'm sure it exits.  I will update with a link when I find it.

Comment: i use the  DotSpatial.Positioning and i can connect to my device, and received geo data in real time,  the device is passive an it can save geo data the problem that i cant access to the data saved.

Comment: When you connect the device (like connecting the USB) does it let you browse the data files like a camera, or thumb drive that you connect via USB?  In that case, maybe the saved points are already on their flash memory card in the form of files that you can browse to.  If that is the case you should be able to access them in code as well.

Comment: hi ted,  i still with problems to read the device, i can read on real time data, but i cant read the information that are storage. when i connect de device dont it let me browser the data storaged, i need a comamnd o script that i cant read on c#.... thanks for your help

Comment: Try finding info on the Antaris4 and u-blox5 USB drivers and go from there.